# Two Gameobjects collides although they are not on the same place

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `Gameobject` called `ball` and another called `floor`. As can be seen in the code, when the ball hits the floor, a printout shall be made.

```c#
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    bg = GameObject.Find(bg_name);

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "floor")
    {
        //bg.GetComponent<ControlGame>().deleteBall();
        //bg.GetComponent<ControlGame>().recreateBall();
        print("Ball hit floor");
    }

    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "rope")
    {
        bg.GetComponent<ControlGame>().ToggleIsShot(false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have moved the floor now, such that the ball and the floor has different depth. Still, the printout is made although the two `Gameobjects` are not touching. See the screenshots below:
[image]
[image: Printout is made as if a collision has occurred.]

The print is in the lower left corner. Why is that?

According to the comment below, the z-value does not have an effect. But I have also a collision detector for the rope, which is a Bezier-curve with an `EdgeCollider2D` attached to it. When the rope passes the floor, nothing is triggered in `onCollisionEnter2D`.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    bg = GameObject.Find(bg_name);
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "floor")
    {
        print("floor collision");
        bg.GetComponent<ControlGame>().ShootBall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, these are `Collider2D`.

You only changed the **Z** (depth) position of the floor which basically is completely ignored in a 2D game / by 2D physics.

As you can also see in the GameView for the Physics 2D the objects are still aligned and colliding.

---

> Why isn't it also working for collision between rope and floor?

Please checkout the [Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for which collisions/trigger can be detected.

→ At least one of the objects has to be a `Rigidbody2D`.

If the rope is e.g. moved by script then it has to be a `Kinematic` → in this case also the floor would need to be a `Rigidbody2D` and not `Kinematic`.

The reason I guess it worked just fine for the ball is because it already is a non-kinematic `Rigidbody2D` so able to detect collisions with static colliders.

Comment: Ok, but than the other problem is that the rope does not detect the floor.

Comment: Does it maybe have another Layer? Or `Is Trigger` enabled? Are there Rigidbody2D?

Comment: No, they are on the same layer, isTrigger is not enabled. There are no RigidBody2D:s attached to floor or rope. Rope can detect the ball so something is working. Tried to add static RigidBodyies, but that did not do any difference.

Comment: Please see my update and checkout the [Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: I have a static collider to the floor and a rigidbody2d attached to the rope, it does work if I select the rope's Rigidbody to be dynamic. If it is dynamic or static it does not work. But in the documentation it says:

Rigidbody Collider
"This is a GameObject with a Collider and a normal, non-kinematic Rigidbody attached. Rigidbody colliders are fully simulated by the physics engine and can react to collisions and forces applied from a script. They can collide with other objects (including static colliders) and are the most commonly used Collider configuration in games that use physics."

Comment: The thing is, using dynamic makes the rope fall to the bottom due to gravity...